# How I can install 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 version of php7.0-common

Tags: server, apt

So I want to install php7.0-mcrypt with apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt
```

and this is error I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-mcrypt : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) but 7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What should I do? How I can install 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 version of php7.0-common?

Comment: try this `sudo apt -f install php7.0-mcrypt`

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install php7.0-common --reinstall` and give me php7.0 version

Comment: Ensure that you only have repositories for the version of Ubuntu that you are actually running.

Comment: As my suggestion is to add php7 repository and try to install again; according to my experience, this will works.

Comment: Can you give me output of `sudo apt-cache policy php7.0-mcrypt`

Answer (score 1):

As the error shows,there is dependencies conflict between `php7.0-common-7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3` & `php7.0-common-7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1` since `php7.0-mcrypt` needs `7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3` but `7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1` is the one going to be installed.

Use `aptitude`,`sudo apt-get install aptitude`
To simply solve dependencies conflicts as it will give options to do that,

To install do `sudo aptitude install php7.0-mcrypt` then choose the suitable option that will solve your issue, aptitude will suggest several potential resolutions.

Comment: This is not an `apt` issue, here cleanly mention that dependency issue.

Comment: did you even understand the answer?

Comment: yes, what you think about this ?

Comment: Did i say any where on that answer that there is an `apt` issue?

Comment: also add this http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/php7.0-mcrypt/download

Comment: the package is on the `ubuntu xenial-security main universe` mirror of which the OP already as so there is no need to add any `ppa`.

Comment: now if you don't mind,would please take back your down vote.thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might happen because of upgraded dependencies from third party ppas. Install ppa-purge and use it to remove unwanted ppas. (Be careful. Do not remove the essential ppas.) 
Removing them via ppa-purge will downgrade dependencies, remove and install some packages.(removing them from other methods might not do that.)

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:yourppahere
```

And then do this:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt
```